# RCA cable with plastic pin - what's its purpose?

Tags: audio, rca

I noticed that my computer was playing sound out of only one speaker. The speakers are connected with a 3.5mm => 2*RCA cable, and when I inspected it, I found that the right RCA plug's inner pin was plastic (picture below). I replaced the cable with a regular cable, and now both speakers have sound.

The cable says `Microlab` on it, so it probably came with the speakers themselves ([Microlab FC-330](http://www.microlab.com/?r=21systemen&st=full&id=431)), though I'm not positive about that.

**My question:** What is the purpose of this kind of cable? Why would it be shipped with speakers?

[image: 3.5mm-2RCA]

Comment: I'd guess the metal contact came off and the plastic is what is beneath it (much cheaper than a massive metal pin) and remained standing alone and without much use.

Answer (score 2):

As @Arsenal correctly noted, it used to be a metal-coated plastic pin, and the metal broke off. I just discovered that after dissecting the cable with a knife. I also discovered that such knife can cut one's finger if one's not careful.
[image: band-aid thumb]

Comment: Curiosity has hurt a lot of people, but the knowledge gained often comes with a feeling of accomplishment offsetting the pain you went through - well done! (hope your finger will get all right again).

Comment: It might be worth checking that the lost bit of metal has not pushed all the way through the socket and is not now lying on your motherboard.

Comment: Commiseration...

Comment: @HandyHowie: No, I think it will be rattling around inside the speaker.

Comment: @DaveTweed Of course.  Looking forward to the next question - "Why is my speaker rattling?"